# Best practices for sharing a python dictionary between functions in an imported module

Tags: python, dictionary, module

Relatively new to python and I'm curious as to the best method to pull off sharing/modifying a dictionary between functions within a module. Example:

some_module.py

```
import requests

my_dict = { 'url': 'www.difficult.com', 'keys': None, 'params': None }

def set_keys(keys):
     my_dict['keys']=keys #these are needed for every request/
 
def set_limit_param(param):
     my_dict["params"]["limit"] = param #not needed for every request

def make_request(added):
      r = requests.get(my_dict["url"] + added,headers=my_dict["keys"],params=my_dict["params"])

 def do_thing1():
     make_request("/thing1")  
 
 def do_thing2():
     set_limit_param("75,000")
     make_request("/thing2")
```

In my use case some_module.py is imported within another script.

- Calling some_module.do_thing2() modifies my dictionary with values I don't really want present when I call some_module.do_thing1().
- However I want the data added when calling some_module.set_keys(key="blahblah") to persist within the dictionary.

I've experimented a bit with my_dict.copy() and copy.deepcopy() but it seems cumbersome to do that within very function that modifies my_dict. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you are modifying the dict, I would recommend an object (from a [standard class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)):

```
import requests

class Requester():

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = { 'url': 'www.difficult.com', 'keys': None, 'params': None }

    def set_keys(self, keys):
        self.config['keys']=keys #these are needed for every request/
 
    def set_limit_param(self, param):
        self.config["params"]["limit"] = param #not needed for every request

    def make_request(self, added):
        r = requests.get(
            self.config["url"] + added,
            headers=self.config["keys"],
            params=self.config["params"]
        )

    def do_thing1(self):
        make_request("/thing1")  
 
    def do_thing2(self):
        set_limit_param("75,000")
        make_request("/thing2")

# create
my_requester = Requester()
```

Then, generally in your code you use this object instead of a module.

Even if there will be only one instance of such class, objects are generally best to store some data along with some methods to these data.

---

Another approach would be leave the methods as they are and use a plain dict (as you did), but don't store it in the methods' module. Tread your module just like a collection of stateless methods and store/define the data (dict) separately:

```py
# requester.py

import requests

def set_keys(my_dict, keys):
    my_dict['keys']=keys #these are needed for every request/
 
def set_limit_param(my_dict, param):
    my_dict["params"]["limit"] = param #not needed for every request

def make_request(my_dict, added):
    r = requests.get(my_dict["url"] + added,headers=my_dict["keys"],params=my_dict["params"])

def do_thing1(my_dict):
    make_request(my_dict, "/thing1")  
 
def do_thing2(my_dict):
    set_limit_param("75,000")
    make_request(my_dict, "/thing2")
```

```py
# my_app.py

import requester

my_dict = { 'url': 'www.difficult.com', 'keys': None, 'params': None }

requester.set_keys(my_dict, 1)
requester.do_thing1(my_dict)
```

---

> Calling some_module.do_thing2() modifies my dictionary with values I don't really want present when I call some_module.do_thing1().

This sounds like you need 2 different dicts - to avoid modifying one by another. Depending on what you do in `do_thing1` and `do_thing2` functions I would also consider separate them to different classes/modules.